# Alternative Azure resource to Azure Webb App to run a background service

Tags: azure, .net-core

I have a service, (.net core 3.1), that receives messages, a lot of them, and stores them in a DB.
The original is baked into an API and deployed as an App Service.

The App Service works fine. Great for the API and the Web but I'm uncertain whether it's the best choice for the service which I now intend to separate from the App Service. It's more or less background worker that just collects data and saves it.

I would like to know if there are any other more suitable Azure products other than App Service or should I go with another App Service?

Answer (score 2):

It seems your use case basically fits to serverless scenario. All your messages processing can be handled by Azure Function.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/serverless/serverless-business-scenarios
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/serverless/serverless-architecture